# Dynamically Add Form Elements in MVC3 Razor Create View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to create a form with a group of text boxes and every time a user clicks the add button those text boxes will be recreated as many time as the user clicks the add button. Here is a picture of what I am looking to do.[image]

### Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Client/MyMove/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Client/MyMove/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Move move)
    {
        var viewModel = new CreateMoveViewModel();
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            move.UserId = currentUserId;
            db.Moves.Add(move);
            move.AddMoveItem(2);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(move);
    }
```

### Create.cshtml

```
@model MovinMyStuff.WebUI.Areas.Client.Models.CreateMoveViewModel
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h1>Post a Move</h1>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-item-group last">
        <div class="form-item half">
            <div class="editor-label">
                Start Date
            </div>
Editorfor for Model1...
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_MoveItem")
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="submit-button-wrapper">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Post" />
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go Back", "Index", null, new { @class = "link-text" })
</div>
```

### ViewModel

```
namespace MovinMyStuff.WebUI.Areas.Client.Models
{
public class CreateMoveViewModel
{
    public CreateMoveViewModel()
    {
        Moves = new Move();
        MoveItems = new MoveItem();
    }
    public Move Moves { get; set; }
    public MoveItem MoveItems { get; set; }
}
}
```

### Partial View

```
@model MovinMyStuff.Domain.Entities.MoveItem

    <div class="editor-label">
        Choose Area of Your Home
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MoveItemArea)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MoveItemArea)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Choose Your Item 
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MoveItemType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MoveItemType)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Quantity
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
    </div>
Other Properties of model...


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MoveId)
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I've been trying to do something similar with the added complexity of having to add validation to fields as well

Answer (score 6):

I very strongly invite you to read the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). It contains an example of how to achieve what you are looking for. It covers the challenges you will encounter with the default model binder when starting to implement this. To overcome those challenges with the collections indexes the author uses a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper.

Comment: Is this solution still accurate for this scenario after few years? or there is something better?

Answer (score 2):

Well i will tried to create a partial View with the model that you need, The key will be to add the html generated from the partial view each time that click the button with ajax for example:

Your model

```
 public class example
 { 
     public int Length { get; set;}
     public int Width  { get; set;}
     public int Height {get; set;}
 }
```

Your Action

```
public ActionResult Example()
{
     return View();
}
```

Your Partial View

```
@model FooExample.Model.Example    

@{
     Layout = null;
 }

<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Length)  
</div>
<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Width)  
</div>
<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Height)  
</div>
```

Your Principal View

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddRows" />

<table id="addViews">
     <tr>
        <td>
        </td> 
     </tr>
<table>
```

Now this is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnAddRows").click(function(){

       $.ajax({
            url: 'your path to the action',
            data : 'if you need to pass parameters',
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function(data){
               $("#addViews").append("<tr/><td>"+data+"</td><tr>");
           }  
       })

   });

});
```

Comment: I'm on it... give two minutes

Comment: Won't that generate html for each item where all inputs have the same id and name? In that case I don't think the default model binder will be able to build a list of models back in the action when submitted.

Comment: defined your editor for, to instead to generates id generated classes

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation to how I've implemented similar situations in the past:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583792/1373170

Its more complicated since it required to support editing and deleting as well.
The main idea is to have a hidden template (created with an `EditorTemplate`), used for creating new rows, and a bit of JavaScript to automatically name all new items to a way that will be automatically interpreted by MVC's default binder, and transformed to the appropriate List of ViewModels in the Action.

Comment: I looked at your example and it looked good but I did not know how I would relate it to my code above...

Comment: Well, in my case it had to be done entirely client-side, plus I already had an `EditorTemplate` defined that could render a single "row". Since I wanted my Action to receive all rows as a List of ViewModels, what I did was first render my template row (what would be displayed when you hit "add") on a hidden div. And when the user clicks on "add" you'd take the contents of that hidden div, clone it with jquery, attach it as a last item, and rename the IDs of all inputs to what MVC would expect. But in my situation I only went to the server when I needed to save.

Comment: Now, given that you are using Telerik extensions for MVC, can't you use their Grid http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax? I think you could pull all this off without actually doing much of the heavy-lifting.

Comment: I guess I could use telerik's grid but I think this could be easy with some custom editor template possibly?

Comment: I'm sure there must be easier approaches. I personally couldn't use Telerik, which is why I had to do it manually. Now, you can also checkout Knockout.js, this example looks pretty similar to what you are attempting to do isn't it? http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Comment: The problem with EditorTemplates and Lists is that MVC numbers each "item", so in order to get that back to the server through a standard POST and using the default model binder, you need to make sure those indexed names are correct.
You do have one other option though: You can have all your rows have exactly the same input names (which the default binder would expect to be arrays), and implement a custom Binder for your ViewModel, that will collect the information from your POST and build the model back. That would simplify UI but complicate your binder a bit. But using Telerik may be easier.

Comment: I created an editor template. I only use telerik for the date picker and nothing else. I think that editortemplate will be clean. I am going to bed and will pick this up tomorrow. Thanks for your thoughts. Maybe we can touch base tomorrow. ( :