# Removing first div created from IEnumerable<HouseholdMember> makes binding null on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, ienumerable

I have read several posts but none quite answer my problem. I am using C#, VS2012, and MVC3.  I have a very healthy ViewModel that has a second level List.  I use a for loop in my view to create a div for each resident with inner divs for name, age, relationship.  This works well and populates from the database correctly.  Developer tools show that it is correct HTML and the name attribute (from TextBoxFor(m => Model.Defendant.HouseholdmemberListing.ElementAt(0).Name).   I do have a hidden input to hold Model.HouseholdMemberListing.ElementAt(0).Id.

On the view there is a Remove link at the end of each entry.  The script simply removes the parent div container for the that row.  All of this is in a BeginForm.  If I remove the first HouseholdMember and click the Submit button, the view model has the HouseholdMemberListing nulled.  If I click the second and Submit there will only be one entry.  If I click the third entry then there are two.  It seems that getting the list out of order still messes up like MVC of past.

I thought MVC3 was supposed to be handling these correctly.  Is it necessary to still use BeginCollectionItem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because after deleting, indexes in your collection will corrupted. Default MVC binder watch indexes of collection starts with 0 (0, 1, 2, ...). If one of this is absense, it doesn't watch next items.

You need to recovery indexes after deleting (they should be in standart order from 0 to n - number of elements).

I suggest you to recalculate indexes before submitting form. Good luck!

Comment: How do you recalculate indexes before submitting the form?

Comment: You should write some js code for enumerate your elements on page, and set their Id and Name (e.g. you can find brackets or underscore for identify place for index)

Comment: @UserBlueOne, also you can see this question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579065/how-to-dynamically-create-remove-elements-and-allow-model-binding-to-kick-in